# Why is Indium Tin Oxide (ITO) transparent to visible light and have low transmission to infrared light?

Tags: optics, material-science, optical-materials

I read that Indium Tin Oxide transmits most of visible light while blocking a high percentage of infrared light.
What is the principle behind this property?

Comment: when I was still in the business, we referred to Indium Tin Oxide as *"Indian Tim" Oxhide*. This meme is now permanently inserted into your DNA.